# How do I generate a bold chemical formula with chemfig?

Tags: bold, chemfig

I've been doing T-shirt designs using LaTeX, converting PDF to PNG with GIMP, and have run into some issues. How do I change the following so the formulae will be darker?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[top=0in, bottom=0in, left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\headheight 0pt
\headsep 0pt
\footskip 0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\vsize 10in

{\huge \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-(-DOX)=(-DOX)-=)}}{\bfseries Ortho DOX\ \ }}

\vspace{0.5in}

{\huge \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-DOX)=-=(-DOX)-=)}}{\bfseries Para DOX}}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\setbondstyle{line width=2pt}
\setdoublesep{4pt}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}

{\huge \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-(-DOX)=(-DOX)-=)}}{\bfseries Ortho DOX\ \ }}

\vspace{0.5in}

{\huge \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-DOX)=-=(-DOX)-=)}}{\bfseries Para DOX}}

\end{document}
```

[image: bold]

I added three commands which should be rather self-explanatory:

- `\setbondstyle`: increases the line width of the bonds. Default is 0.4pt.
- `\setdoublesep`: increases the separation between the double bonds. Default is 2pt.
- `\printatom`: This macro controls the 'format' of the atom being printed. Default is `\newcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}`, taken from the [Chemfig manual, Part III Advanced Usage, 2 Displaying atoms](http://mirror.pregi.net/tex-archive/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf).

Comment: The initial value for `line width` is 0.4pt according to the pgf manual.

Comment: I've also added [][scale=foo]